# Website printing and flash

Tags: flash, cross-browser, printing

I have a client who has a flash gallery on most of her pages. When the page loads the gallery starts fading in images in a loop.

Now, when someone decides to print the page, browsers other than IE7/8 will print the blank space before fade in instead of the first image, IE7/8 will print the current state of flash regardless.

I have tried adding `<noscript>` which doesn't help, the browser is trying to print the (currently blank) flash file.

What I need to do using whichever combination of PHP, JavaScript, CSS, ActionScript you can think of is to get the browser to print that first image but otherwise preserve the functionality of the gallery (start from blank, then fade in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a print style-sheet that hides the flash content and displays an otherwise hidden div containing the first image of the gallery.

Answer (score 0):

read this

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=printing_1.html

also catch print event in js